# Trouble with active element in my html page

Tags: php, html, css, class, styles

I'm looking for a method to use CSS to change the display properties to the nav element related to the page that is currently active.

For example, if the user is on the Home page, the 'Home' button in the navigation is styled differently.

I use the following code:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="<?php echo $sito ?>/index.php">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $sito ?>/page1.html">page1</a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="<?php echo $sito ?>/page2.html">page2</a>
</li>
```

when I selecte page1 or page2, the home button remain active!

Comment: what is your code to add the active class there?

Comment: you need to keep your li values in array like `array('index'=>'home','page1'=>'page1')` etc .. then check for key in `$_SERVER` if exists the add class ... for this to implement you need to keep you menu in header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var $links = $('li');
$links.click(function(){
   $links.removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KwdwZ/3/)**

Comment: This style will not remain there when your navigates to oher the page .. OP wants to change the style of the tab he is currently on .. I suppose

Comment: Look at the URL`s - its not about switching classes with JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<li <?php if($page=='home'){?> class="active"<?php }?>>
    <a href="<?php echo $sito ?>/index.php">Home</a>
</li>
<li <?php if($page=='page1'){?> class="active"<?php }?>>
    <a href="<?php echo $sito ?>/page1.html">page1</a>
</li>
<li <?php if($page=='page2'){?> class="active"<?php }?>>
   <a href="<?php echo $sito ?>/page2.html">page2</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand - You have a static pages.
If so - just add `class="active"` for corresponding `<li>` in page1.html and page2.html

In page1.html it will be 2nd `<li>` element but in page2.html - last one